# Maximum liklihood vector form in RBM

Tags: machine-learning

In the last equation why we take transpose of v

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say dim($v$) is m x 1, dim($W$) is m x n, and dim($h$) is n x 1 (convention is that vectors are column vectors).

dim($vW$) would be (m x 1) x (m x n) = ? (I think this would be a tensor, and I don't think this is what they were going for because it couldn't then be dotted with $h$)

dim($v^{T}W$) is (1 x m) x (m x n) = 1 x n

Then

dim($v^T{t}W$h) is (1 x n) x (n x 1) = 1 x 1